# Howto pass XStream reference into camel for marshalling

Tags: java, apache-camel, xstream

Sample code from http://camel.apache.org/xstream.html

> If you would like to configure the XStream instance used by the Camel for the message transformation, you can simply pass a reference to that instance on the DSL level.

```
XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.aliasField("money", PurchaseOrder.class, "cash");
// new Added setModel option since Camel 2.14
xStream.setModel("NO_REFERENCES");
...

from("direct:marshal").
  marshal(new XStreamDataFormat(xStream)).
  to("mock:marshaled");
```

But this code is wrong, because `org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.XStreamDataFormat` constructor accept only String. How to configure custom `com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream` in camel?

I dont want to use XML, my application is using Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have it done fast, instead of going through "marshal" you can redirect to a marshalling "bean" that will do the marhsalling in the way you need.

```
from(...).bean('marshallingBean').to(...)
```

### Complete code

```
@Autowired
FooDeserializer fooDeserializer;

@Bean
public RouteBuilder route() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("direct:marshal")
                    .bean(fooDeserializer)
                    .to("mock:marshaled");
        }
    };
}
```

### `FooDeserializer.java`

```
@Component
public class FooDeserializer {

    private final XStream xStream;

    public FooDeserializer() {
        xStream = new XStream();
        xStream.aliasField("money", PurchaseOrder.class, "cash");
    }

    public Foo xmlToFoo(String xml) {
        return (Foo) xStream.fromXML(xml);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use

```
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.xstream.XStreamDataFormat;
```

and not

```
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.XStreamDataFormat;
```

for class

```
new XStreamDataFormat(xStream)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution.

```
final XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.aliasField("money", PurchaseOrder.class, "cash");

from("direct:marshal")
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) {
                String xmlConverted = xStream.toXML(exchange.getIn().getBody());
                exchange.getIn().setBody(xmlConverted);
            }
        }).to("mock:marshaled");
```